# ¿Cómo puedo acceder una variable/método desde otra clase?

Tags: java

Apenas inicio en poo(java),  tengo una duda con el manejo de clases y sus relaciones, cuando se tiene por ejemplo una clase `A` con atributos;

```
public class A{
    private String nombre;

    private String saludar(){
        System.out.println("Hola mundo");
    }
}
```

Y una clase `B` en la cual esta declarada una referencia a la clase `A`;

```
public class B{
    private A a;
}
```

Podría en la clase `B` utilizar tanto atributos/métodos de la clase `A` en la clase `B`?

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: PD. La mejor forma de plantear este tipo de preguntas siempre será con código de ejemplo! Así mismo, la respuesta será con código que seguro será más fácil de seguir para ti

Comment: *...entonces de esa manera yo podría en la clase B utilizar tanto atributos-métodos de la clase A en B*  Es correcto, dado que en la clase `B` tendrás un miembro que es de la clase `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuesto. Siempre y cuando utilices `public` o `protected` en el atributo o método que quieres acceder desde afuera de la clase.

- `public` accede esta variable o método desde cualquier clase
- `protected` accede esta variable o método desde otra clase que este
  en el mismo paquete o desde una subclase(sin importar en que paquete este)
- `private` esta variable o método es privado, no se puede acceder fuera de su propia clase.

```
public class A{
   public String nombre = "Noel";

   public String saludar(){
       System.out.println("Hola mundo");
   }
}

public class B{
   private A a;

   public B(A a){
       this.a = a;

       a.saludar(); // podemos llamar este metodo por que es public
       System.out.println("Me llamo "+a.nombre);// igualmente podemos acceder a este atributo por que es public
   }
}
```

Comment: Para añadir algo más de valor a la respuesta, decir que se suelen poner los métodos o atributos que no se quieran tocar de una clase, en privado, pero luego los `setters` y `getters`en publico. De esta manera la variable en sí está "segura(?)" pero se pueed acceder y editar!